# need a way to apply css in a listcell (javafx)

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm a newbie on java fx and I don't know enough of css, that's why I wasn't able to make an acceptable research and post it here (with a research I believe it would be easier to find a proper solution). Anyway, I didn't mean to dupplicate (I didn't understand answers of similar questions about applying css on javafx controls).

So, the situation consists in a listview (see image below):

[image: Listview with listcells]

My problem is that I can't find a way to set the last item in **bold** (the focused item, 9x17 - Mother's Little Helper).

I accept suggestions related to best ways to do what I said, and even if it's a better way to do it without using css I would be glad to hear that. I need just a way to set the last item in bold. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want the last item in the list bold or is it the selected item in the list which you want bold?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the last item of a list bold use this approach:

```
listView.getItems().get(list.size()-1).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
```

This does not update the list when you add items to it at a later point though.
Here is an example for a working updateable listview:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private ObservableList<Label> list;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

            ListView<Label> l = new ListView<>();

            root.getChildren().add(l);

            list = l.getItems();
            list.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Label>() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(
                        javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Label> c) {
                    for(Label l : list){
                        l.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: normal");
                    }
                    list.get(list.size()-1).setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
                }
            });

            l.getItems().add(new Label("test"));
            l.getItems().add(new Label("test"));

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I know it's not the most beautiful thing to run a foreach over a list but it is pretty fast and i could not figure out another approach.

EDIT: Maybe you should create an update method and only call the style manipulation when a bunch of items have been added and there are no others to be added immediately. The problem with the example above is that it gets called after every single new entry.

Cheers,
Laurenz